# php sql update only filled in fields

Tags: php, sql

(this is all basic php voor school)
I made a form where you can update your account information, when you hit the submit button, it will come to this php code. If a field is not filled in, it does not need to be updated, I tried  "WHERE field IS NOT NULL" but it does not seem to work, it gives an empty record...

(variables are all in dutch, sorry)

```
$klantnummer = $_COOKIE['klantnummer'];
$naam =($_POST["naam"]);
$adres =($_POST["adres"]);
$postcode =($_POST["postcode"]);
$gemeente =($_POST["gemeente"]);
$leden =($_POST["gezinsleden"]);
$huidigemeterstand =($_POST["huidigemeterstand"]);
$vorigemeterstand =($_POST["vorigemeterstand"]);
$provincie =($_POST["provincie"]);


//set up connection and choose database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("opdracht3", $con);
mysql_query("UPDATE waterstand SET naam = '$naam', adres = '$adres', postnummer = '$postcode', gemeente = '$gemeente', vorigemeterstand='$vorigemeterstand', huidigemeterstand='$huidigemeterstand', provincie='$provincie', aantalgezinsleden = '$gezinsleden'
WHERE klantnummer = '$klantnummer' AND naam IS NOT NULL");`
```

ofcourse I need to ad the rest of the 'field' IS NOT NULL but for example I only use 'naam'.. but it does not work :/

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_ functions` as a start, they are deprecated. Start using PDO, it is much better and much safer

Comment: Is the default values in your database fields set to NULL? If they are set to '' or similar, then IS NULL check won't return true.

Comment: @Ben Carey: This is the way we learn it at school, but I will check it out , thank you!

Comment: @user1830235 See the messages at the top of each of these pages! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. I would inform your teacher that he needs look at the php.net website and read up on this. All of the `mysql_` functions are being deprecated :-)

Comment: The WHERE clause "references" the records as it is before the update, i.e. your IS NOT NULL condition tests if a record has a value <> NULL before a possible UPDATE could take place.

Comment: I think @VolkerK hit the nail on the head, are you trying to do user input validation with SQL? That won't work. You need to validate the input *before* you try and insert it, with PHP or similar.

Comment: mhhh oke thx everybody! So I need a PHP function like empty() or something to check if the fields are filled in or not? but then i need to check every variable with an if function? (=long code)

Comment: you can either use some kind of for/each loop or use the filter extension, see http://docs.php.net/filter

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest if you keep this part of the logic away from the database, e.g.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if ( !mysql_select_db("opdracht3", $con) ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// contains strings/parameters/identifiers ready-for-use with mysql  
$sql_params = array(
    'fields' => array('naam', 'adres', 'postcode', 'gemeente', 'gezinsleden', 'huidigemeterstand', 'vorigemeterstand', 'provincie'),
    'klantnummer' => mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['klantnummer']),
    'updates' => array()
);

// the names of the POST-fields are the same as the column identifiers of the database table
// go through each identifier
foreach( $sql_params['fields'] as $f ) {
    // put in here the conditions for "an empty field, e.g.
    // if there is such POST-field and its value is one or more "usable" characters long
    if ( isset($_POST[$f]) && strlen(trim($_POST[$f])) > 0 ) {
        // create a new `x`=`y` "line" as in UPDATE ... SET `x`='y'
        // and append it to the array $sql_params['updates']
        $sql_params['updates'][] = sprintf("`%s`='%s'", $f, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$f]));
    }
}

// the "lines" in $sql_params['updates'] need to be concatenated with , between them
// join(', ', $sql_params['updates']) does that
// insert that string and the parameter klantnummer into the query string
$query = sprintf(
    "
        UPDATE
            waterstand
        SET
            %s
        WHERE
            klantnummer = '%s'
    ",
    join(', ', $sql_params['updates']),
    $sql_params['klantnummer']
);
```

(untested)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot @VolkerK , but I think the code is not readable for me :D, we are learning the basics and I do not understand this code, I'm sorry :/.I checked out the filter page your gave me, I suppose to use the filter_has_var function, right?

Comment: Sorry, that link is probably misleading as it helps you little with modifying the query string. Comments added to the example script.